# I'm looking for a Windows hosting provider that supports custom os images (like AMZN EC2)

Tags: hosting, windows-server-2003, amazon-ec2, virtual, cloud

I've come to love [Amazon's EC2 service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Elastic_Compute_Cloud) and I'm looking for something similar that supports the ability to save a running Windows server image and start new instances from it.

I contacted [GoGrid](http://www.gogrid.com/) (the feature is planned in future) and [Mosso](http://www.mosso.com/) (no joy)

Anyone know of any hosting/cloud providers that can dothis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just received a message from Amazon to the effect that that they will be [supporting Windows Server on EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/windows/) this fall.

Wahaay!!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like dealing with licensing issues would be nightmarish for the host.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how licensing would be any different than for a co-lo provider.

Answer (score 0):

AT&T's [Synaptic Hosting](http://arstechnica.com/news.ars/post/20080806-atampt-has-head-in-the-clouds-with-synaptic-hosting.html) allows this, though I'm sure you'll pay through the nose, as it's "enterprise".

Answer (score 0):

GoGrid as announced to offer the feature this fall. Look at http://www.flexihost.co.uk and http://www.elastichosts.com (both in the UK) as well as http://www.appnexus.com.

I have heard that www.rightscale.com (it's kind of a nice interface to EC2 hosting) will support Windows sometime in the future.

With a lot of manual tweaking you can already run Windows on EC2 using virtualization inside a Linux virtual machine:
http://www.howtoforge.com/amazon_elastic_compute_cloud_qemu

I have a short list of cloud hosting companies on my website:
http://hotware.wordpress.com/2008/07/25/a-short-cloud-hosting-link-list/